# How to clean up this code to make it easier and more adaptable?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for advice on how to clean up this code to make it easier to read, and more adaptable if I need to expand the number of lines. Specifically, how to tell the code which cells to choose, and which values to locate in each cell.

```
qWordCount = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Words").Range("B:B"))

Cells(2, 5) = "Hyphens"
Cells(2, 6) = tHyphenCount
Cells(2, 7) = Round(qWordCount / tHyphenCount, 2)

Cells(3, 5) = "Brackets"
Cells(3, 6) = rBracketCount / 2
Cells(3, 7) = Round(qWordCount / (rBracketCount / 2), 2)

Cells(4, 5) = "Quotation Marks"
Cells(4, 6) = vQuotationMarkCount
Cells(4, 7) = Round(qWordCount / vQuotationMarkCount, 2)

Cells(5, 5) = "Full Stops"
Cells(5, 6) = zFullStopCount
Cells(5, 7) = Round(qWordCount / zFullStopCount, 2)

Cells(6, 5) = "Question Marks"
Cells(6, 6) = yQuestionMarkCount
Cells(6, 7) = Round(qWordCount / yQuestionMarkCount, 2)

Cells(7, 5) = "Colons"
Cells(7, 6) = xColonCount
Cells(7, 7) = Round(qWordCount / xColonCount, 2)

Cells(8, 5) = "Commas"
Cells(8, 6) = wCommaCount
Cells(8, 7) = Round(qWordCount / wCommaCount, 2)

Cells(9, 5) = "Semicolons"
Cells(9, 6) = uSemiColonCount
Cells(9, 7) = Round(qWordCount / uSemiColonCount, 2)

Cells(10, 5) = "Exclamation Marks"
Cells(10, 6) = sExclamationMarkCount
Cells(10, 7) = Round(qWordCount / sExclamationMarkCount, 2)

Cells(11, 5) = "Word Count"
Cells(11, 6) = qWordCount
```

Comment: You could extract a `Sub` that writes the values in columns 5, 6, and 7, but judging by the number of variables you're using, I'm sure there's a better way to architect this that abstracts away most of the hard coded values you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your code the way it is, but you could also do something like this

```
public sub embed(lRow as long,lCol as long,strFirst as string,strMacro as string,dNum as double, dDen as double)

    cells(lRow,lCol) = strFirst
    cells(lRow,lCol+1) = application.run(strMacro)
    cells(lRow,lCol+2) = Round(dNum / dDen, 2)

end sub

public sub main()

    embed 2,5,"Hyphens","tHyphenCount",qWordCount,tHyphenCount
    'Replace the remainder of the blocks of code with embed calls, aside from the last 2, which doesn't fit this model

end sub
```

Comment: You'll need to specify which sheet `cells` should write to, too

Answer (score 0):

You can create generic procedure for it. Please note that code deals with the special case of *Brackets* when `rBracketCount` itself is being divided by two. In order to apply this division, pass `True` for `is_divide` parameter. By default, it's `False`.

```
Sub Dump(topLeftCell As Range, sCaption$, wordcnt#, cnt#, Optional is_divide = False)
    topLeftCell.Resize(, 3) = Array(sCaption, cnt, Round(wordcnt / (cnt / IIf(is_divide, 2, 1)), 2))
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Call Dump([A1], "Commas", 100, 50)
End Sub
```